# How do I create a functional api using django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use mailgun's api on a landing page made through unbounce.com, however I discovered that I can't make requests client side. I do have django set up, so, I'd like to use that to make api calls to mailgun instead.

So, my question is how do I create using django-rest-framework, an API that would make the api calls for me and return the response. I have used drf before, but mostly serializing models, and this time I'd like to make a function-based api

I expect to make a call to mailgun and pass a parameter called email so that I can use something like domain.com/api/mailgun/email="email@email.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use APIView for your endpoint and requests library for mailgun api

```
class MailView(APIView):
    def get(request):
        email = request.query_params.get('email', None)
        """ 
         some valdiations ..
        """
        response = requests.get('http://mailgun-api/')
        return Response(data=response.json())
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to pass 'params=' in `requests.get`.

Comment: I wrote just the road map, not complete example